# How to color only a few patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am making a small model in NetLogo, but one certain line of my code refuses to work

```
if (aantal-diensten = "gemiddeld") [ask n-of 50 patches [set pcolor pink]]
```

I want 50 patches to turn pink when the user selects `gemiddeld` in the interface-tab. The problem is that all patches turn pink. I think there is something wrong with the combination of if and ask n-of, because n-of does work if I remove the if statement.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me at first glance; we might need a bit more context to figure out what's wrong. Just a guess, but could it be, for instance, that this line is nested inside another loop (another `ask` block, for example) which causes it to be executed many times, causing all patches to eventually turn pink?

Comment: @NicolasPayette
You are right, it is nested in an other loop. I wrote in the to setup procedure ask patches [setup-services] and there I wrote the code above. 
I'll try to fix it, thank you!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Let us know here if you stumble upon more difficulties...